# Testing JQuery UI Sliders in Cucumber

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, selenium, cucumber

I have a set of 10 JQuery UI sliders that need to be tested in some fashion.

Specifically, I need to drag each slider handle and observe the current value of the slider.

I've tried using various methods on the Selenium driver to grab it, like:

```
handle = find(".ui-slider-handle")
find("#category_weight_#{cw.id}").native.drag_and_drop_by(handle,'10px')
```

But I keep getting deprecation errors, and can't find decent examples of using the new action builder in selenium.

Anyone doing this, have any advice?

Comment: Check this answer for Selenium-based solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138449/how-to-move-horizontal-slider-or-vertical-slider-of-jquery-using-selenium-webdri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code for sliding:

```
  page.execute_script "s=$('#slider');"
  page.execute_script "s.slider('option', 'value', #{value})"
  page.execute_script "s.slider('option','slide').call(s,null,{ handle: $('.ui-slider-handle', s), value: #{value} });"
```

Comment: Was hoping for something that simulated a real users interaction in the browser, instead of doing it programmatically.  Thanks though, I may end up doing it your way

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/jquery-slider-drag-drop-rspec-capybara/) worked fine for Capybara/Selenium tests.

I tested [noui slider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) for RoR application with Cucumber/Capybara