# How to drag a slider in a webpage to a particular position using python webdriver

Tags: python, webdriver

I have a slider in a webpage and its default position is at 0 , say i have to move it to position 5.How to move it to this position.Currently i am using the method:

```
move_by_offset(x-offset,y-offset)
```

but not able to know how to give the values as it behaves randomly..

Comment: In Java I do it like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11139314/1300626) maybe this could help you...