# How to move range input using Selenium (in Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I have been using Python Selenium for quite some time and I have been happy with it until I got this new requirement which I am supposed to set sliders on a web-page ([here](http://99.243.40.11/#/HouseSold)) to certain values and then let the page run its scripts to update the page with the results.

My problem is how to set the slider min and max knobs () using Python Selenium. I have the tried the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138449/how-to-move-horizontal-slider-or-vertical-slider-of-jquery-using-selenium-webdri) and my code is below.

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import datetime
import time
import mysql.connector



def check2(driver, slidebar, sliderknob, percent):

    height = slidebar.size['height']
    width = slidebar.size['width']

    move = ActionChains(driver);
    # slidebar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='slider']/a")

    if width > height:
        #highly likely a horizontal slider
        print "off set: ", percent * width / 100
        move.click_and_hold(sliderknob).move_by_offset(500, 0).release().perform()
    else:
        #highly likely a vertical slider
       move.click_and_hold(sliderknob).move_by_offset(percent * height / 100, 0).release().perform()

    driver.switch_to_default_content()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')

os.environ["PATH"] += ":/home/mike/software"

os.environ["PATH"] += ":/usr/local/bin/"
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://99.243.40.11/#/HouseSold")
    els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@class="input high"]')
    print 'els.len = ', len(els)
    e = els[0]
    ens = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="pointer high"]')
    en = ens[0]
    check2(driver, e, en, 70)
    time.sleep(20)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Unfortunately not working for me. 
Please let me know if you know of any clue. 
Much appreicate your help.

Regards,

Comment: You just made copy/paste of provided solution... Are you sure you have totally the same `HTML` for your slider? Provide `HTML` code of your slider element

Comment: I changed my code and updated it thanks to your question. So now it finds the input range element to get the width/range from and then looks for its knob which is a span element and then tries to move the knob relatively. For one thing, the example I got inspired from is used for JQuery based sliders but mine is an HTML tag where the actual html tag is a <input type="raghe" > and knob is a span tag. But overall the same idea should work for both cases a it only deals with mouse actions. I think I am missing a point on how to select the knob element.

Comment: Did you try to record the actions in Selenium IDE, and then viewing the exported code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I think you can follow last comment's and it will give you the clue.

Actually I did and got some good results. First you need use Selenium IDE to find the knob you like to move and then do sth like below to move it like below.

Let me know if that helps you.

Cheers,

```
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://99.243.40.11/#/HouseSold")
    en =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[6]")
    move = ActionChains(driver)
    move.click_and_hold(en).move_by_offset(10, 0).release().perform()
    time.sleep(5)

    move.click_and_hold(en).move_by_offset(10, 0).release().perform()
    time.sleep(5)

    move.click_and_hold(en).move_by_offset(10, 0).release().perform()
    time.sleep(5)

finally:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks it is very helpful. But if I want to move slider to the left 
move_by_offset(-10,0) is not working.